# Java Code Style

Tags: java, styles

Does Java Code Style say anything about numerical suffix in variable naming?
Which of this two options is acceptable (or maybe both)?

```
final Computer computer_1 = new Computer();
final Computer computer1 = new Computer();
```

Comment: It's not common practice to use underscore in Java variables. The second one would be more java-like style

Comment: If you had a collection of `Computer` objects, i.e. more than one, I'd generally expect to see some data structure being used, e.g. an array or `List`. This would remove the need for numbering the variables and reduce repetitiveness of code (depending on their actual usage).

Comment: When using `constant` it is prefer to be the whole field in capital letters and with underscore separation between each two words, and try to avoid numbers, ex: `COMPUTER_ONE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can read [here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.1-identifier-names), computer1 is the standard. Underscore should e used only in constants.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't say anything in particular about numbers in their naming conventions.
Although they do mention camelCases to be the general convention for objects like in your case

final Computer computer1 = new Computer() would be the preferred option here
Although its not a good naming practice.
You would generally name your objects to describe their *use*

Answer (score 0):

There is wrong or right. But if you want to use a standard, I would recommend the [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)

Due to this: Variables in Java should be written in lowerCamelCase. So it is:

```
Computer computer1 = new Computer();
```

Answer (score 0):

If we consider that Oracle's coding style is the official one (except Constants), then underscoring is not official. So the second choice is more acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The name of a variable, function or class should answer all the big questions. It should tell you why it exists, what it does, and how it is used.

As computer1 is standard and computer_1 is not, use the always standard version to facilitate the work to future developers that maybe are going to read your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can find lots of java coding style guides if you browse through the internet. some of answers mention here. From a different perspective lets see a scenario where name consist of 2 words (`computer one`) instead of `computer1`.

There are 3 ways commonly declare this.

01.camelCase

```
Computer computerOne = new Computer();
```

02.underscore_separated

```
Computer computer_one = new Computer();
```

03.nospaces

```
Computer computerone = new Computer();
```

i would say most understandable way of declaration is camelCase. Secondly no spaces. Underscore separated method used mostly in pl-sql or any sql related programming languages.